# Incrementing rvalue in C++

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue, post-increment, pre-increment

Does anyone know why this code does not compile

```cpp
int main() {
  int i = 7;
  int j = ++i++; // error: lvalue required as increment operand
}
```

while this code compiles perfectly?

```cpp
int main() {
  Int i{7};
  Int j = ++i++; // OK!
}
```

The class `Int` is defined as follows:

```cpp
struct Int {
  int i;
  Int(int i = 0) : i{i} {}
  Int& operator++() {++i; return *this;}
  Int operator++(int) {Int t{*this}; ++i; return t;}
};
```

When I compile the first code snippet it fails with error "lvalue required as increment operand." The other one compiles and works as expected.

Comment: Native types do not have assignment operators. Class objects typically do. `7=8;` is illegal while `Int(7)=8;` is.

Comment: Why would you ever write something like that?

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the differences between xvalues and prvalues. Both are rvalues but an xvalue is also a glvalue which means one can take it's address, assign to it, and otherwise operate on it. Class types, but not native types, will convert a prvalue to an xvalue when needed.

Let's start by looking at:

```
int i = 7;
int j = ++i++; // error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

Since `i++` has higher precedence than `++i` the last line can be re-written:

```
int j = ++(i++);
```

While `i` is an lvalue, `i++` is a prvalue. In this example it has a value of 7 while `i` is now 8. `++8` is invalid since you can't increment, decrement, or assign to a prvalue.

Now let's look at:

```
struct Int {
    int i;
    Int(int i = 0) : i{ i } {}
    Int& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
    Int operator++(int) { Int t{ *this }; ++i; return t; }
};
int main() {
    Int i{ 7 };
    Int j = ++i++; // OK!
}
```

Here, `i++` returns an prvalue which is then converted to an xvalue through [temporary materialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.rval).  It is temporarily materialized so the pre ++ operator can now operate on it thus setting the temporary object's value to 8 and assigning it to `j`.

Comment: In your example `i++` returns an prvalue, I believe. (It being a class type doesn't affect this.) Which is then materialized to an xvalue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right. It returns a prvalue which is then temporarily materialized to a xvalue. Edited to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. do we get some issues from absense of  constructor and assignment operator here?   `Int j = ++i++; ` is technically a call to eligible `Int::Int(Int&&)` or Int::Int(const Int&), not an assignement

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie  No issue. `Int` has all it's move/copy ctors as well as assignments.